# How to plot data sets each of different length?

Tags: plotting

I run a code to NSolve long polynomial `1+a+x^2+b*x^4...+x^10`for a particular input parameter with range of values say `{a,0,7,1}`.  The solution give me a 'Table' of complex roots values with each row having different length for example:

```
{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
 { 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14},
 { 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20},
 { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1+i, 1+2*i, -1, -2, -3},
 { 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20},
 { 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14},
 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

So each row represents the value of `a` and each column represents the value of `x` solution.  Therefore for particular value of `a=1` , the NSolve gives me 7 solutions or 7 roots.  Therefore each `a` has a solution of different length.  I have to plot column wise or each column in complex plane for range of `a`.  The problem I have is that I cannot do `PadRight` with zeros.  I think I have to leave null space as null which means that some columns do not have data points.  How do I plot this table of complex values with unequal length in columns or rows in 2D or 3D without padding with zeros or any other value?

Thanks in advance,

WolfMath Ver.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"  *)
```

Note: use `I` not `i` for complex numbers

```
roots = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14},
   {4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20},
   {4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1 + I, 1 + 2*I, -1, -2, -3},
   {4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20},
   {1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14},
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
```

It is not clear to me how you want this plotted. One approach

```
plotData = Table[{Re[#], Im[#], n - 1} & /@ roots[[n]], {n, Length[roots]}];

ListPointPlot3D[plotData, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im, Index}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1/2, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** In 2D the roots are difficult to see since there is significant overlap of the values

```
plotData2D = Table[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ roots[[n]], {n, Length[roots]}];

ListPlot[plotData2D,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im}), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: n represents "a" or degree of polynomial?   Real and Imaginary are great, but 3rd axis should be in values of 'a' instead of polynomial degree. Each row has assigned value specified in 'a'

Comment: @Aschoolar - The "index" is the (row number -1), i.,e., `a` running from `0` to `6` since you gave seven data sets.

Comment: Can index be modified?  In my realistic data, I have decimal numbers 0.1, 0.2 etc. zz = {i,0.0,2.2,0.2}

Comment: @Aschoolar - you can make it anything you like. I just used integers starting at zero because that is what you stated in the question. To start at zero and go in steps of 0.2: `plotData = 
  Table[{Re[#], Im[#], 0.2 (n - 1)} & /@ roots[[n]], {n, 
    Length[roots]}];`

Comment: can you put it in 2D?